# If $A\subset\mathbb R^n$, a point $p\in\mathbb R^n-A$ is a limit point iff for every $\delta>0$, $B(p,\delta)\cap A$ is infinite.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am doing an introductory course in Real Analysis and I have to prove the following statement:

> Suppose $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ and $p\in\mathbb R^n$, $p\notin A$.
>   Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> (a) $p$ is a limit point of $A$
>
> (b) for all $\delta >0$, the collection $B(p,\delta)\cap A$ is infinite

Here $B(p,\delta):=\{x\in\mathbb R^n\ |\ \|p-x\|<\delta \}$. Proving (b) $\Rightarrow$ (a) is elementary. I have some trouble formulating the proof of (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b), though. I get that the idea is that, since $p$ is a limit point and $p\notin A$, $p\notin B(p,\delta)\cap A$, yet $B(p,\delta)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ so $\exists q\in B(p,\delta)\cap A$ with $p\neq q$. Choosing $\delta':=\|p-q\|$, we can construct a new ball $B(p,\delta')\subset B(p,\delta)$, which is a strict subset. Now again, since $p$ is a limit point, this new ball contains another point, enabling us to do a similar construction, and so on. My problem arises when I'm trying to concretize this procedure (in an elegant and formal manner). Any suggestions? Please note that I have only just begun this course and I do not really know any advanced analysis, so a simple explanation would suit me best!

Comment: Hint: show first that a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed. What happens if $B(p, \delta) \cap A$ is only finite?

Answer (score 1):

(1) implies (2) .

Suppose $B(p,\delta)\cap A=\{x_1,..x_n\}  $a finite set . Then set $r=\min \{ |p-x_i| : i=1,2..n \}$ . By hypothesis $r\neq 0$ and so $r>0$ . Can you verify that $B(p,r)\cap A$ contains a point point different point $x_1,x_2,..x_n$ because $p$ is a limit point . Draw a ball and take points in it if you find it hard to imagine .

(2) implies (1)

Choose $\delta_1=1$ and see that there is a at least one point $t_1$ from $A$ such that $d(t_1,p)<1 $.This is possible because $p$ is limit point .  Now construct a sequence $\{t_n\}$ inductively as follows : having chosen $\delta_1,\delta_2,..\delta_{n-1} $ chose $\delta_n=\frac{1}{n} $ and a point $t_n$ such that $d(p,t_n)<\frac{1}{n}$ . Notice how the condition of infinitely many is used here . So 
You get a sequence $t_n$ such that $d(p,t_n)<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$ . So $t_n\to p$ and $t_n\neq p$ for all $n$( as $p$ does not belong in $A$ but all of $t_n$ are in $A$ . This basically the definition of a limit point .